# Rails: How to set return values from a map method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a footer helper to display links

```
  def footer_helper
    resources = ["tweet","questions"] # and perhaps something more
     resources.map do  |resource|
       if current_page?(controller: resource.pluralize, action: 'index')
         link_to "New #{resource.humanize}", {controller: resource.pluralize, action: 'new'}
        else
         link_to "#{resource.pluralize.humanize}",{controller: resource.pluralize, action: 'index'}
       end
    end.join(" ")
  end
```

and in footer.html.erb, I wrote:

```
<%= raw footer_helper %>
```

Problems:

1. The `.join(" ")` is pretty ugly. Is there any better syntax for this? If I do not use it, the `.map` will return an array containing link html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def footer_helper
  ["tweet","questions"].map do  |resource|
    if current_page?(controller: resource.pluralize, action: 'index')
      link_to "New #{resource.humanize", send(:"new_#{resource}_path")
    else
      link_to resource.pluralize.humanize, send(:"index_#{resource}_path")
    end
  end.join(" ").html_safe
end
```

and in **footer.html.erb** simply:

```
<%= footer_helper %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the join is fine, but you are instantiating a variable that you don't need to. Also, you can use send for the paths. The code is below.

```
def footer_helper
  ["tweet","questions"].map do |resource|
    if current_page?(controller: resource.pluralize, action: 'index')
      link_to "New #{resource.humanize}", send("new_#{resource}_path".to_sym)
    else
      link_to "#{resource.pluralize.humanize}", send("index_#{resource}_path".to_sym)
    end
  end.join(' ')
end
```